# Do not eat garlic in the evening

Tags: nutrition

It's common to hear that garlic should be eaten in the morning and should not be eaten in the evening.

Many people even use the following saying for garlic:

> Medicine in the morning, poison in the evening.

It's the old saying in the Czech republic. People refer to it as the wisdom of the ancestors. But nobody is able to say the reason.The exact translation is in my question. You can try google with "cesnek jed vecer" = "garlic poison evening". You will find many links with it, but no explanation.

Is this saying true? What are the rational reasons for not eating garlic in the evening? Or is this saying only a myth?

Comment: Probably has more to do with the fact that more people have sex in the evening than during the day when they work.

Comment: I'm confused. Shouldn't there be a claim attached to this proscription? Something like "Don't eat garlic in the evening because if you do _______." Otherwise, we are not only being asked to verify the correctness of the claims, we are also being asked to discover the claims themselves.

Comment: What is the claim? Where is it said? Any sources on the claim?  I have personally never heard that so I would like to have some source of this.

Comment: @Wertilq It's the old saying in the Czech republic. People refer to it as the wisdom of the ancestors. But nobody is able to say the reason.The exact translation is in my question. You can try google with "cesnek jed vecer" = "garlic poison evening". You will find many links with it, but no explanation.

Comment: @xralf - I suggest the next time you hear someone say it you immediately ask them "POISON HOW?" and if they say "I don't know...?" you can slap them about the face with a trout until they promise not to repeat it ever again. (be sure to have a trout handy)

Comment: @AndrewHeath I already heared from a few people the reason "It can irritate gall bladder or pancreas", though I haven't found an evidence of it and especially that in the evening. Vice versa I found article about positive effect on gall bladder stones.

Comment: Then edit your original question to say something like "If you eat garlic in the evening can it irritate your gall bladder?" and you might finally start getting some answers. :-)

Comment: @AndrewHeath I'd like somebody to show the whole saying as false and that there is no need worry to eat it in the evening.

Comment: @AndrewHeath - Trout is poison. Don't carry it in your hands.

Comment: It seems to me @DVK has the right idea. To most people, garlic breath isn't exactly a turn on.

Comment: @DavidBrenner Breath is fine. It's good aphrodisiac :-) But breath could be unpleasant during the day for a lot of people I meet I can't afford garlic breath.